# VB.NET: How can you activate the childform when only the control inside is clicked?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

*edit: OK, so this is my real problem, below scenario happens only when the form is MDIChild.. thanks for anyone that could provide me with the code

I have a form with labels, panels, buttons etc.  Where I'm having problem is, while form2 is my active window/form and I clicked on a control inside form1, the form1 does not activate itself.  What I would like to happen is for form1 to activate even when it's not the form I clicked, only the control inside it (any control)..

I'm thinking that if I clicked a control on the form, there's an event fired on the form.  If I could only know of that certain event, that would help - maybe (coz I could just add Me.activate on that event if it exists).  I've tried searching for series of events when a control (ex. label) is clicked but to no avail.  I hope that someone could help me with this one.

Thanks in advance.

*edit

i will just try to make my question more understandable..

> How can I activate the form when only the control is clicked (say, label or textbox)? My forms does not activate or focused when I click inside it except the form itself..

I can do this on one control..

```
Private Sub Label1_Click - Handles Label1.Click
   Me.Activate()
End Sub
```

But what if I have 20 controls (labels, buttons, textbox, combobox, etc)? See? =)

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot so we can see what you mean?

Comment: @Chris, sorry I think it will take time for me to upload screenshot for this one.  i still hope you could get what im saying above.  How can I activate the form when only the control is clicked (say, label or textbox)? My forms does not activate or focused when I click inside it except the form itself..

Comment: Ah. I see. You need some kind of generic click handler. Maybe something along these lines: http://www.universalthread.com/ViewPageArticle.aspx?ID=73

Comment: i'll take a look and get back to you after, thnx chris

Comment: is there another way around? it still looks like a lot of hardwork. I mean, I have more than 7 forms and each form has more than 10 controls.  I would like them all to do the same. is there a AddHandler code that adds all controlclicks.. say "for each control.click".. you know?

Comment: I think this might be just the job: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?679207-Add-handler-for-each-control-in-panel. If my VisualStudio wasn't updating I would customise the code for you ...damn updates!

Comment: I have tried having two forms, `Form1` and `Form2` alongside one another. Clicked on `Form2` then clicked on a dropdown etc on `Form1` and it reactivates the `Form1` and opens the dropdown. I can't see any issue. This is without using any generic click handler or using any `activate` commands

Comment: My **GUESS** is that you are showing the focused form modally, otherwise, any form you click should get focus when you click on it... Look into the differences between `Form.Show()` and `Form.ShowDialog`... Again, just a guess...

Comment: @Chris, i think it would work only for dropdown.. but what about clicking a label? I think that if you click on the dropdown, it would fire an event to the form that makes focus on it.. but it doesn't happen when you click on a label.. maybe if someone could guide me through series of events when you click a dropdown, that would do a lot.. thanks anyway Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **non-MDI** forms, the form is **automatically activated** when you click any control inside it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: this answer does not apply to MDI applications.

I think what you really want to know is which one of your forms is currently the foreground window (if any). The first thing you need to understand is that a form instance lives inside a window, but the window's behavior is controlled somewhere higher up. Similar to how a form instance is identified by a variable pointing to the instance, a window can be identified by what's known as a window handle.

Knowing this, the proper way to find out whether a form is the "active" form is to:

1. find out the window handles of the windows containing our instances of `Form1` and `Form2`
2. find out the window handle of the foreground window (which can be any window)
3. compare the value found in step 2 to all of the values found in step 1

Perhaps you'd then like to fire an event if the foreground window changes, but I'll leave the actual implementation up to you. There are probably several ways to perform step 1 and 2, but I can't give any solutions off the top of my head. Hopefuly I've put you back on the right track.

**EDIT**

Alternatively, you can use the form's `Containsfocus` property. If its value is True, you can safely assume that your form is the foreground window. I didn't find out about this property until after I wrote my own implementation, which I'll show you anyway:

**One module containing only a windows API call**

```
Friend Module NativeMethods

    Friend Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32.dll" () As IntPtr

End Module
```

Calling this method will return the window handle of the foreground window (if any).

**One module containing the extension method for the `Form` class**

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module FormExtensions

    <Extension>
    Public Function IsForeground(f As Form) As Boolean
        Return (f.Handle = NativeMethods.GetForegroundWindow)
    End Function

End Module
```

Calling this method returns whether the specified form *f* has the same window handle as the foreground window.

**Usage example**

You could use a `Timer` that periodically checks whether a form is the foreground window.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private WithEvents timer As New Timer With {.Enabled = True}

    Private Sub timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timer.Tick
        If Me.IsForeground() Then
            Console.WriteLine("this instance of Form1 is the foreground window")
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Like I said before, you can use `Me.ContainsFocus` instead of my extension method and it will work just fine.